# change javascript array format

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a linear javascript array like this:

```
A = ["1","2","3"];
B = ["4","5","6"];
```

From Data that is already a long javascript array but is formatted like this:

```
var A = [];
var B = [];
A[0] = "1";
B[0] = "4";
A[1] = "2";
B[1] = "5";
A[2] = "3";
B[2] = "6";
```

What is the easiest way to convert the javascript array from the 2nd example to the 1st?

With the code in the 1st format the filesize is smaller, and the data easier to edit.

Comment: Um... aren't those equivalent? What exactly are u trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't understand the question. They are the same array, just created with different code.

Comment: They are both exactly the same arrays. Changing the way they are set up will not affect the way they can be used.

Comment: I edited the question to include some reasons why.  I am trying to achieve the same array written like the 1st example.  Im not sure what is so unclear.  The comments seem to understand fine but not want to answer?

Comment: You are effectively creating the same arrays in both examples. Why do you care about the size of the JavaScript source file?

Comment: Would you like to just quickly edit the text file without doing it yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the second code in the console and then type

```
console.log('var A =', A);
console.log('var B =', B);
```

you will get in the console the text you need to paste back in your code..

If your variables are global try running

```
console.clear();
for (var global in window){
    if (window.hasOwnProperty(global)){
        if (Array.isArray(window[global])){
           console.log( 'var',global, '=', window[global] );
        }
    }
}
```

after your script. (*it might show other arrays as well, just copy those you want..*)

Comment: That 2nd code looks like it did the trick - with all the variables and " in the right place.  Thanks.

Comment: got it working thanks.  Took 60% of the size off the file, and is easier to edit.  Not sure what everyones problem was.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can get the short text form of any object using the [`JSON.stringify`<sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function:

```
JSON.stringify(A);
// returns '["1","2","3"]';
```

Comment: this looks good but where do I put the code JSON.stringify(A); ?  I tried it after calling the array.  Do I need to document.write it?

Comment: @Jon You can use it after you create the array. To see it, you can `document.write` it, or `console.log` it, or `alert` it, or any other way you like to display it.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should do something like this and copy paste the string from the console:

```
var A = [];
var B = [];
A[0] = "1";
B[0] = "4";
A[1] = "2";
B[1] = "5";
A[2] = "3";
B[2] = "6";

function getOutputStr(arr) {
    var output = '[';
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        output += '"' + arr[i] + '",'
    }

    output = output.substring(0, output.length - 1);
    output += ']';
    return output;
}
console.log(getOutputStr(A));
console.log(getOutputStr(B));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkUzT/)